# Do iOS and Android support the html5 tag <main>?

Tags: program-entry-point

Do the iOS and Android browsers support the html5 tag <main>? I read that do not.  Dispel my doubts, please.

Answer (score 0):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main#Browser_compatibility), it is supported in anyhow modern versions of iOS and Android browsers ([Safari 7.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history#Safari_7) released in 2014, so you don't really have to worry about versions older than that)